# Swift Forma de mostrar variáveis

Tags: swift, variáveis

Estou a terminar um pequeno projecto para aprender Swift mas existe um pequeno problema em juntar mais variáveis no *output*.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Nome: UITextField!
 @IBAction func CalcularIMC(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    imc = ((p * 200) / (a * a)) * 100 / 2
    var str = "";

    if imc < 16
    {
        str = NSString(format: "O seu IMC é %.2f, Peso Abaixo", imc) as String
        lblresultado.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
}
 lblresultado.text = str;
```

Faltam de certeza alguns parêntesis mas foi apenas para mostrar. 
O meu problema está aqui :

```
(format: "O seu IMC é %.2f, Peso Abaixo", imc)
```

Neste texto quero mostrar também a variável `Nome` que está no inicio do código que mostrei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O tipo nativo do Swift não é NSString, e sim String. Todos os initializers disponíveis para NSString também existem para String. Se quiser colocar o texto do seu text field direto na sua string você tem que fazer da seguinte forma:

```
str = String(format: "%@ o seu IMC é %.2f, Peso Abaixo", Nome.text!, imc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja assim:

```
str = NSString(format: "%@ o seu IMC é %.2f, Peso Abaixo", nome, imc) as String
```

Comment: Deu-me erro ao mostrar o texto. <UITextField: 0x79e964e0; frame....
text  = " O nome que eu escrevi" clipstobound... uma coisa assim s:

Comment: Me parece que nome não é uma string.

Comment: O Nome é texto. Será o nome do utilizador por exemplo : Maria

Comment: Tente assim: str = NSString(format: "%@ o seu IMC é %.2f, Peso Abaixo", "Maria", imc) as String

Comment: Assim funciona s:

Comment: Então. Isso quer dizer que não esta chegando um texto para a função. A função precisa receber uma string e nome não é uma string. Me parece que ela é um objeto. Você deve passar algo, tipo: Nome.Text. Eu não tenho o SWIFT aqui para validar isso, mas vá nesse caminho.

Comment: Eu para receber a Var Nome Criei uma caixa de texto . @IBOutlet weak var Nome: UITextField!